# SharePoint 2013 Custom WCF Service

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2013

In SharePoint 2013, what is the difference between creating a custom WCF service:

```
       - under ISAPI folder (_vti_bin/...)
       - under Layouts folder (_layouts/...)?
```

Answer (score 0):

-> under ISAPI folder (_vti_bin/...)

Comment: Yep, I know that, but I have seen cases when services are under _layouts so I was just wondering what is the difference if any?